# I am trying to save high scores with pickle, but how do I add to an already pickled document and then get the max?

Tags: python, python-2.7, max, pickle

I am trying to save high scores in a game that I am creating, but each time I do a pickle.dump, it overwrites my previous data. Any help?

Comment: `pickle.load`, modify, `pickle.dump`?

Comment: Load the previous dump, add your scores, and then dump it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pickle, you pickle one object at a time, so you might have to pickle multiple times.

```
>>> score = 1
>>> f = open('highscores.p', 'wb')
>>> pickle.dump(score, f)
>>> f.close()
>>> score = 15
>>> f = open('highscores.p', 'wb')
>>> pickle.dump(score, f)
>>> f.close()
>>> f = open('highscores.p', 'rb')
>>> print pickle.load(f)
1
>>> print pickle.load(f)
15
>>> print pickle.load(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError
```

To fix that, use a while True and a try, except:

```
>>> highscores = []
>>> 
>>> while True:
...     try:
...         highscores.append(pickle.load(f))
...     except EOFError:
...         break
...
>>> print highscores
```

Now all that is left is to get the maximum. You can use the built in [`max()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function to do this:

```
>>> print max(highscores)
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to load your existing pickle'd object, modify it, and then dump it again with the modifications.

Comment: Yes, but how do I modify the pickle file.

Answer (score 1):

```
pickled = pickle.load(open('myscript.p'), 'rb')
#then print the pickled information, and change it as needed.
#then dump the edited version back to the original file
```